# Render only one render layer?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render one specific render layer, which I have already set up on the layers panel. I'm saving it as EXR multilayer to edit on nuke, but whenever I open up the EXR file on nuke, it contains all other layers like the screenshot, but they are just black, empty. This is making the EXR file size huge.

How can I only render one layer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you check "Render Single Layer" in the view layer properties ? Please add a screenshot of your compositor nodes

Comment: @Gorgious Hi, yes, I've uploaded the screenshot

Comment: So what's the output file size exactly ? You are populating it with quite a few layers already, it is supposed to take a lot of space since there is no compression

Comment: @Gorgious the file size isn't the main problem, you can see from the nuke screenshot, on the other layer tab, the render layers I didn't select are all included, and I want to know how I can get rid of those and only get the passes from the layer I've selected :(